# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON')

Tags: discord.js

My code was going great and everything was working fine. Then I thought I would add a user info command to my bot. So I followed a tutorial about it and finished the `.js` file. This is what I wrote:

```js
const { ContextMenuInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "userinfo",
    type: "USER",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ContextMenuInteraction} interaction
     */
    async execute(interaction) {
        const target = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.targetId);

        const Response = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("AQUA")
            .setAuthor(target.user.tag, target.user.avatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512})) 
            .setThumbnail(target.user.avatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
            .addField("ID", `${target.user.id}`)
            .addField("Roles", `${target.roles.cache.map(r => r).join(" ").replace("@everyone", " ") || "None"}`)
            .addField("Member Since", `<t:${parseInt(target.joinedTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, true)
            .addField("Discord User Since", `<t:${parseInt(target.user.createdTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`, true)
        
        interaction.reply({embeds:  [Response], ephemeral: true})
   
    }  
}
```

Now in my `index.js` file (which i've named `bot.js`), I've written this code:

```js
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}
```

To of course read the commands from my commands file. When I run the terminal it had this error in it: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON')`

When I deleted the `userinfo.js` file, everything worked fine again. What did I do wrong please help.

Answer (score 0):

From your current code it looks like you followed a tutorial for reading the commands from the commands folder. You get your error because in your exported command, there is no data property. However, when following the official `discord.js` guide to register slash commands, there is a property like this:

```js
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('echo')
    .setDescription('Replies with your input!')
```

However, your command file will not work properly unless there is a command handler because normal `discord.js` slash commands does not have any property like `name` or `permissions`. These properties are all declared in the `.data` property which is where your error is originating because your exported command does not have it. So to solve the problem, either create a command handler which would work with your current code or format your current code to this:

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('userinfo')
        .setDescription('user info'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        /* Execute your code */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm i guess that would work. But I dont want it to be a slash command. I want it so i click on somebody on member list and then go to app and userinfo. I dont think it would use the same thing

Comment: Also i followed this tutorial for user info command: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyRx1sOevII&list=PLQfxpktrTzhK-w4sdeIV6lNEdr-a1ke2Z&index=10

Comment: This is the solution you're looking for @Lliakos. Just use [`ContextMenuCommandBuilder`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/ContextMenuCommandBuilder) instead of `SlashCommandBuilder`. Other than that, this answer solves your issue.

Comment: I put this code: 
```module.exports = {
    data: new Builders.ContextMenuCommandBuilder()
        .setName('userinfo')
        .setDescription('user info'),
    async execute(interaction) {
```
and in terminal it says this:

```ReferenceError: Builders is not defined
```

Comment: Nvm fixed that. But now it says that .setDescription isnt a command so i deleted that.And now this : ```throw this.error;
    ^

CombinedError: Received one or more errors``` Idk man

Comment: Can you post the full error, it might show where the error was originating